# Почему в таблице системных вызовов linux из семейства exec присутствует только execv?

Tags: linux, c

Появилась потребность перехватить системный вызов exec, посомтрел в таблицу. Почему в таблице системных вызовов linux из семейства exec присутствует только execv? Через нее реализованы другие exec?

Comment: если кратко — да…

Comment: Строго говоря, в заголовочном файле `<bits/syscall.h>` определены два системных вызова `exec`: `SYS_execve` и `SYS_execveat`. Через `SYS_execve` реализуются все функции `exec*`, а через `SYS_execveat` реализована функция `fexecve`.